# How to pick videos in imagepicker in expo?

Tags: video, react-native, camera, expo

Expo built-in [image picker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/sdk/imagepicker.html) allows to pick images, how can you use it to pick videos.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need.

> let result =  ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
>
> mediaTypes:'Videos',
>
> });

///all----Images or Videos

Answer (score 1):

Searching the [Github repository](https://github.com/expo/expo), shows two issues for this [1](https://github.com/expo/expo-sdk/issues/38) [2](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/120) which point to this [feature request](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/camera-component) that is *In Progress*. They state that it won't be ready until SDK20 which is due for release in August.

If you cannot wait, you can poke around the source code for undocumented options to try and get this working but I wouldn't recommend it since they may be bugs and the API may change in in newer releases. For example, you can check out these files:

- [Line 87 here](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/9a9dfb4103cb0cd5bfff8a97710350321655059f/ios/versioned-react-native/ABI18_0_0/Libraries/CameraRoll/ABI18_0_0RCTImagePickerManager.m) for possible video picking
- Or [line 98 here](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/ea7336d33a1bdc71a0b8afc36162884cbf8b5ffb/ios/versioned-react-native/ABI16_0_0/Exponent/Modules/Api/ABI16_0_0EXImagePicker.m) for possible video picking
- And [line 65 here](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/9a9dfb4103cb0cd5bfff8a97710350321655059f/ios/versioned-react-native/ABI18_0_0/Libraries/CameraRoll/ABI18_0_0RCTImagePickerManager.m) for possible recording in video